# SSIS Package returning less rows with MDX query

Tags: ssis, mdx, dataflowtask

I'm trying to extract data from a cube using MDX, when I run the query in SSMS I get 500K rows (same result I get when I use excel to connect to the cube), however, when I put the query into a SSIS package and execute it I get only 100k rows. The package executes just fine (completes correctly), it doesn't show any errors, warnings, anything so not sure why I'm not getting the same number on rows :(.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Could you please tell us what OLEDB provider version you are using in your connection?

Comment: Here are the connection string details **Provider=MSOLAP.5;Integrated Security=SSPI;format=tabular;** and I'm using a **OLEDB** data flow task.

Comment: Thanks.  How long is the query running in SSMS?  Are you hitting your timeout threshold?

Comment: Are you sure you are pointing to the same database?

Comment: Is the same user executing the query? Could it be that a Role/Perspective is at play?

Comment: Timeout is set as 0 so I don't think we are timing out, also the package executes without any errors at all. Query takes around 30 - 35 min to run in SSMS. Same user is running the queries in SSMS and in the SSIS package.

Comment: Did you try a profiler trace on the SSAS server while the SSIS query was running?

Answer (score 0):

Well I still don't know what was causing this issue but I was able to pull all of the data by using a linked server query instead of a direct MDX query to the cube.

Answer (score 0):

If you dump it to RAW file SSIS dumps the whole extract. Then you can import from the RAW file. It's not an ideal but solves the issue.